# Python typing Callable class property

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have an inherited class member that is an optional callable and I want to type hint it.

```
import typing

class BytesDecoder(typing.Protocol):
    def __call__(self,data:bytes)->None: ...
    
class BaseClass:
    _decodeBytes:typing.Optional[BytesDecoder]=None

    @typing.final
    def decode(self,data:bytes):
        if self._decodeBytes is not None:
            self._decodeBytes(data)

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def _decodeBytes(self,data:bytes)->None:
        ...
```

Mypy complains about the derived _decodeBytes method:

> Signature of "_decodeBytes" incompatible with supertype "BaseClass"

I've also tried defining BytesDecoder like `BytesDecoder=typing.Callable[[bytes],None]` but that does the same thing.

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that the problem is that `DerivedClass` implicitly changes the type of `_decodeBytes` from `Optional[whatever]` to `whatever` by defining it directly. At least in Python 3.9 or later, you can fix this with a relatively non-intrusive decorator `@lambda x: typing.cast(typing.Optional[BytesDecoder], x)` applied to the method override.

Comment: (As always, `cast` doesn't necessarily *fix* the problem; it just tells `mypy` to trust your judgement.)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon one solution, though it's not ideal.  In the base class I can create a dummy _decodeBytes() function and then forcibly smash it back to None.

```
class BaseClass:

    def _decodeBytes(self,data:bytes)->None: ...
    _decodeBytes=None # type: ignore
```

It's weird and non-intuitive, but it does seem to make type checking work as expected for derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution may be to make `_decodeBytes` required, but provide a dummy implementation that behaves the same as not calling it at all.

```
import typing


class BaseClass:
    def _decodeBytes(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        pass

    @typing.final
    def decode(self,data:bytes):
        self._decodeBytes(data)


class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def _decodeBytes(self,data:bytes)->None:
        ...
```

The original problem was that `mypy` couldn't verify something like the following was safe:

```
decoders: list[BaseClass] = [BaseClass(), DerivedClass()]

for x in decoders:
    x._decodeBytes = None
```

The assignment is legal according to the static type of `decoders` and for the runtime type of `decoders[0]`, but illegal for the runtime type of `decoders[1]`. Getting rid of the `Optional` status of `_decodeBytes` takes  away the possibility of assigning `None` to *any* object's `_decodeBytes` attribute.